# An equivalent of -javaagent in C#? Or: ways to use a java framework in C#

Tags: c#, java, cross-platform, code-injection, javaagents

This is probably something I should be able to figure out by myself, but I'm not having much luck so I figured I'd ask.

The issue: I'm translating a system from java to C# and they use [a java framework](http://sites.google.com/site/deucestm/) that I'd really like to use, since it takes care of the most complex parts of the system, which I would otherwise have to implement myself. I have the source code of this framework.

I know there are several possibilities for using java libraries in C# (although I'm not familiar with any of them, so I'd appreciate suggestions). So far I've thought of using [IKVM.NET](http://www.ikvm.net/uses.html) to generate a .dll, but I'm not sure what to do next, because in java in order to run the framework with your code [you're supposed to use the option -javaagent](http://sites.google.com/site/deucestm/documentation/getting-started) by adding

`-javaagent:bin/deuceAgent.jar`  (where `deuceAgent` is the framework)

to your java command line. I don't know what the equivalent in C# would be once I have my .dll, or whether there's an equivalent at all.

Any help? Thanks so much.

Comment: Did the following work for you?

Answer (score -1):

well once the DLL is created you can add that DLL as reference in your project and user it...

To add a reference in Visual C# Project you can do the following.

1. In Solution Explorer, right-click the project node and click Add Reference.
2. In the Add Reference dialog box, select the tab indicating the type of component you want   to reference. (In you case it is DLL file
3. Select the components you want to reference, and then click OK.

[image]

After that you can use the same in your coding... You may need to import namespace that are there in Java Class lib and then you can use those class.

Hope this helps.

Thanks,
Jigar